# how to update date & time & region on Windows CE?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

How can I update date & time & region on Windows CE?

I need any C# code for this.

for example: i want to update to: 21/12/2010 05:34 (region format dd/MM/yyyy)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the actual system time has to be done via P/Invoke.  [MSDN has an article on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172517.aspx).  Changing the date format woudl require P/Invoking [SetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906277.aspx), probably with the LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT [LCTYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906223.aspx).